# $L_\infty([0,1], \mathbb{C})$ is it isomorphic to $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{C})$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

By a result of Pełczyński, $L_\infty([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$. That is the case of real valued functions and sequences.

A natural question then is: can we extend this result to complex valued functions and sequences, considering the linear spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ ?

It seems that we may need some notion of complex measures and a stronger version of the Radon Nikodym 'representation' theorem if we like to mimic the real valued result.
Or maybe, simply, the complex case is just the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case and we can apply Radon Nikodym theorem 'coordinate-wise' and consider a product measure. This would generalize of course to $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued functions.

Is there a reference where this was done before?

Comment: I'm having difficulties to follow the question: An $\mathbb{R}$-linear continuous bijection $T: L_\infty([0,1];\mathbb{R}) \to \ell_\infty(\mathbb{N};\mathbb{R})$ extends to a $\mathbb{C}$-linear bijection $L_\infty([0,1];\mathbb{C}) \to \ell_\infty(\mathbb{N};\mathbb{C})$. There's no need to repeat any of the arguments that gave you $T$.

Comment: Are we allowed to state that there is such a $T$? The fact that they are isomorphic stems from complementing one in the other but no explicit $T$ is constructed.

Comment: What definition of two Banach spaces being isomorphic do you use if not the existence of a (bi-)continuous linear bijection between them?

Comment: I agree with @JochenGlueck - but on a separate note, your claim that the complex case is just the ${\bf R}^2$-valued case is not quite right, because one is now requiring the isomorphism to be compatible with complex scalars. In particular, your speculation about ${\bf R}^n$-valued functions is true but one only gets a ${\bf R}$-linear isomorphism, this is different from your complexification question.